# Isolating a Python Application From Internet Access

Tags: python, security, virtualenv

Let’s say that I write an application in a Python virtualenv environment, and it relies on a bunch of packages from PyPI.

Let’s also say that I’m very paranoid—as I should be—about some of the packages (and, more than likely, their underlying dependencies) that I’m using and I’m worried that my application might be “phoning home” due to some nefarious code.

Are there any tools or packages I can use to ensure that no external accesses are being attempted by my application?

I don’t wish to attack this problem from an IT perspective, but from a programming one. Assume that I don’t have root access and cannot control where or on what systems my application is installed.

Comment: If you're running in a virtual environment, don't give it Internet access.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly do this without an insane amount of work. It's of course possible to create a version of Python that would disallow access to hardware, had all the existing networking libraries removed, etc. - but that would be *far* harder than just running the script in a little sandbox (look into containerisation for example)

Comment: Run the app in a docker container with no open ports.

Comment: @Barmar can you point to some documentation for specifying network access with venv? I’ve never heard of doing that.

Comment: if you want proper network isolation, you probably want a docker image or even full blown VM instead of a simple virtual environment. Of course, if you distrust your dependencies that much, and simply pegging version numbers is not enough for you to believe things won't "phone home", then one could make the case that's real paranoia, not the kind you "should be". Don't be paranoid, be secure: vet your dependencies, and peg the version numbers, and then understand that simply by relying on a package manager, you are trusting that package manager to not be compromised.

Comment: A virtual environment is nothing more that some shell-based path manipulation. It has no effect on network accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other than isolating your env in a docker as a devop/IT solution,
Code-wise, these tools can make sure your code isn't connecting to the internet:

- Static Analysis: Tools like Bandit and PyLint look at your code without running it. They can find risky things in your code, like unsafe commands.
- Dynamic Analysis: Tools like Py-Spy look at your code while it's running. They can see if your code tries to connect to the internet.
- Network Mocking: Libraries like responses or HTTPretty can pretend to be the internet. This lets your code think it's connecting to the internet when it's really not.
- Dependency Checking: Tools like pipdeptree and safety look at other code your program needs (dependencies) and tell you if they're safe.